# Union or aggregate into table variable in SQL CMD MODE

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to combine records into one table across databases (and on different servers) when using SQL CMD MODE in SSMS?

```
:Connect Database1
select firstname,lastname from table1
GO
:Connect Database2
select firstname,lastname from table1
GO
:Connect Database3
select firstname,lastname from table1
GO
```

How can I put all the results in one table?

Comment: do the databases reside on the same server?

Comment: No, they don't  reside on the same server. Three different ones.

Comment: then link them to one server and union them or join or what ever you need

Comment: using python c# or such you need toget all tables and use the dataset or dataframe to combine them

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use variables to hold the servers, union the results and use `select into`, it would look something like:

```
:setvar serv1 "server1"
:setvar serv2 "server2"

:Connect $(serv1)
select column into #Result
from database.schema.table
union all
select column from $(serv2).database.schema.table

select * from #Result /* Temp table on server1 */
```